# How to create a horizontal and vertical split view in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit

I am relatively new to working with iOS, and I need some help wrapping my head around the way to construct this view :-)

What I want to accomplish is to have a view with a horizontal and a vertical split, thus making four quadrants, each being an independent view. At the cross between the vertical and the horizontal splits I want to put a draggable button that, when dragged, will control the position of both splits. This button will be relatively big, so it will overlap with the central corners of all four quadrants.

Furthermore, I would like each of the four quadrants to be scrollable in all directions.

I have been looking at ScrollViews, TableViews, and containers, but I really need a pointer in the right direction :-) How do I structure this layout in XCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely want to use a custom container controller (with 4 container views) to do this, assuming that by independent views, you mean separate view controllers. The custom container controller can be set up in IB, by dragging in container views and sizing them how you want. The button would be a subview of the container controller over top the 4 container views. If you want the views in each of the quadrants to be scrollable, then you would need to add a scroll view to each of them, and give them a large enough content view so that they need to scroll in both directions.